# Saving QtQuick Items with multiple states to .png files

Tags: python, qml, qtquick2, pyside2

I'm trying to save visual items that have multiple states as .png images (one png for each state)

I'm calling the item's grabToImage() method in the onStateChanged signal handler but images are only saved after the last state change takes place, creating only one image corresponding to the last set state of the item.

I also tried calling saveToFile() on the python side but that results in a runtime error (see comments in the python code)

**grab_states.py**

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickView


app = QApplication([])

view = QQuickView()
view.setSource(QUrl('grab_states.qml'))
view.show()

rect = view.rootObject()
rect.setState('off')
rect.setState('on')

# RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (PySide2.QtQuick.QQuickItemGrabResult) already deleted.
# rect.grabToImage().data().saveToFile(rect.property('state') + ".png")

app.exec_()
```

**grab_states.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
  id: rect
  width: 100
  height: 100

  color: "black"

  states: [
      State {name: "off"; PropertyChanges{target: rect; color: "red"}},
      State {name: "on";  PropertyChanges{target: rect; color: "green"}}
  ]

  onStateChanged: {
    print('stateChaged: ' + state)
    rect.grabToImage(function(result){
      print("saveToFile: " + rect.state);
      result.saveToFile(state + '.png');
      }
    )
  }
}
```

The saveToFile function is called twice as expected, but only after all the state changes happened, so I only get one image showing the last state and overwriting the first image. If I use different filenames to prevent overwrites then I get two images, both showing the final state.

How can I save the corresponding image for each state of the item?

Comment: This might interest you https://github.com/benlau/sparkqml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 errors:

- You are changing your status without making sure you have already saved the image.
- By doing the above, the value of state will be updated in grabToImage and will point to the previous state.

In both cases the solution is to make sure that the image was saved to change the state. Considering the above, the solution is as follows:

***.py**

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtQuick

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QtQuick.QQuickView()
    view.setSource(QtCore.QUrl('grab_states.qml'))
    view.show()
    rect = view.rootObject()
    rect.setProperty("currentIndex", 0)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: rect
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "black"
    property int currentIndex: -1
    onCurrentIndexChanged: if(currentIndex >= 0 && currentIndex < states.length) state = states[currentIndex].name
    states: [
        State {name: "off"; PropertyChanges{target: rect; color: "red"}},
        State {name: "on";  PropertyChanges{target: rect; color: "green"}}
    ]

    onStateChanged: {
        rect.grabToImage(function(result){
            result.saveToFile(state + ".png");
            currentIndex+= 1;
            console.log(filename);
        })
    }
}
```